# Adding arrows next to an image

Tags: html, css, position

I have a unique homework problem. I'm trying to replicate the layout I have here.

https://ibb.co/fYh6d3m

Inserting an image and centering it is easy enough, ditto for bg colour. However I'm at a loss on how to add the arrows next to the images.

The arrows do NOT have to take you to the next image, they are literally just meant to be interactivee buttons ( ie click on right arrow go to linked in, click on left go to fb, etc ) However this DOES have to be responsive.

The catch is, we can only use HTML and CSS ( Otherwise it would be too easy via Jquery )

Can anyone please help me out here? I've been trying to figure it out for the last 4 hours.

I've pasted some rough code below (please excuse the weird margins/padding on the .left, I was seeing if I could jury rig it in, but it didn't work) and I think I'm on the right track, but I can't seem to find a way to position the arrows on either side of image.

Thank you very much for any help, I appreciate it.

Tried using images, but was told we aren't allowed as they have to be interactive

Spent a good few hours researching, but without the correct terminology, I'm at a loss.

The margin and padding is way off on the .left because I was seeing if I could jury rig it using those, but it has to be responsive as well.

```css
.image2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="images/image2.jpg" class="image2">
  <i class="arrow right"></i>
  <i class="arrow left"></i>

</section>
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this

https://ibb.co/fYh6d3m

With the arrows being interactive via hover states/linking but NOT proceeding an image in a slideshow.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yfh17d4g/1/ This fiddles contains code from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp). I broke the code down to only the parts you needed.

Comment: @RickSibley this is pretty much exactly what I needed. Just one quick question. How would I place the arrows outside of the image ( instead of inside ) ? Thank you a lot, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/yfh17d4g/3/

Comment: @RickSibley

Awesome thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. 

Cheers

Comment: I noticed a bug with the other fiddle I linked. When you shrink the screen down the buttons will not stay on screen. I'm not sure if you will have the same problem but if you do I have created a work around. https://jsfiddle.net/7w4L0h58/1/